# Referencing a class library in a visual studio extension project at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm making a custom extension that will have a window. That window will host a view out of a class library. In the xaml designer I can see the correct view referenced from the library but when I'm debugging the window it will crash when it tries to load the class library dll.

Some of the error log from Fusion

> Message=Could not load file or assembly 'SSMainControl, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

I made a WPF application and hosted the same view which worked fine. the only difference is that the extension loads the reference at runtime. An help is appreciated.

Update: I signed the file and loaded it in through a content view initialized with new MainView(). This actually loads but now I'm getting the same error when I implement the view in the xmal.

These are my xaml statments:

xmlns:mainControl="clr-namespace:SSMainControl;assembly=SSMainControl"

mainControl:MainView />

Comment: If you are working in Debug or Release go to the corresponding folder in the startup project now check whether it contains the DLL needed for SSMainControl. Even though we add the reference in visual studio it may not reach there. Try it.

Comment: It is there. It also gets deployed with everything else to the experimental instance.